# How to split the legend into two row?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
Nu  Cd_ppm  pH
1   0.024   5.51
2   0.023   5.53
3   0.024   5.60
4   0.025   5.60
5   0.025   6.41
6   0.024   6.38
7   0.024   6.42
8   0.026   6.39
9   0.016   6.45
10  0.015   6.46
11  0.016   6.46
12  0.014   6.44
13  0.018   7.00
14  0.017   7.10
15  0.017   7.05
16  0.023   7.01
17  0.030   6.80
18  0.034   6.88
19  0.030   6.87
20  0.035   6.89
21  0.024   6.21
22  0.029   6.18
23  0.028   6.21
24  0.031   6.21
25  0.019   6.43
26  0.023   6.38
27  0.021   6.41
28  0.029   6.39
29  0.027   6.98
30  0.025   6.91
31  0.026   6.71
32  0.029   6.67
33  0.037   6.45
34  0.039   6.41
35  0.038   6.48
36  0.037   6.48
37  0.047   6.42
38  0.043   6.36
39  0.051   6.36
40  0.048   6.40
41  0.033   5.95
42  0.036   6.02
43  0.038   5.96
44  0.038   5.95
45  0.041   6.13
46  0.042   6.14
47  0.040   6.13
48  0.048   6.15
49  NA  NA
50  0.006   6.02
51  0.007   6.06
52  0.007   5.99
53  0.080   5.93
54  0.088   5.89
55  0.079   5.86
56  0.079   5.80
57  0.053   7.84
58  0.051   7.87
59  0.069   7.93
60  0.052   7.95
61  0.046   6.04
62  0.048   5.98
63  0.038   6.28
64  0.045   6.54
65  0.176   6.59
66  0.172   6.14
67  0.176   6.38
68  0.176   6.60
69  0.113   6.10
70  0.116   6.14
71  0.114   6.13
72  0.111   6.11
73  0.095   7.06
74  0.065   7.05
75  0.084   7.03
76  0.063   7.01
77  0.048   7.18
78  0.053   7.16
79  0.052   7.28
80  0.051   7.11
81  0.045   7.61
82  0.038   7.62
83  0.046   7.59
84  0.046   7.60
85  0.025   7.51
86  0.026   7.53
87  0.029   7.49
88  0.030   7.54
89  0.030   6.82
90  0.030   6.78
91  0.031   6.82
92  0.031   6.80
93  0.075   6.95
94  0.079   6.90
95  0.076   6.95
96  0.079   6.93
97  0.059   7.39
98  0.065   7.37
99  0.059   7.42
100 0.061   7.41
101 0.038   7.08
102 0.042   7.14
103 0.049   7.24
104 0.058   7.12
105 0.063   7.11
106 0.068   7.11
107 0.058   7.03
108 0.059   7.13
109 0.072   6.67
110 0.076   6.56
111 0.071   6.66
112 0.072   6.59
113 0.113   6.86
114 0.123   6.87
115 0.117   6.81
116 0.114   6.91
117 0.093   6.71
118 0.091   6.71
119 0.090   6.75
120 0.090   6.70
121 0.087   6.63
122 0.099   6.49
123 0.098   6.52
124 0.099   6.45
125 0.010   8.07
126 0.009   8.01
127 0.010   8.06
128 0.009   8.06

my.formula= y ~ exp(1.5*-x)
Pot=data[c(1:52),]
Pot1=data[c(53:64),]
Incub=data[c(65:76),]
Incub1=data[c(77:128),]
```

```r
library(gridExtra)
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(tidyr)
library(ggpmisc)
library(ggpubr)
library(patchwork) # combine plots
library(gapminder)

p1=ggplot(data=data, aes(x=pH,y=Cd_ppm,col="+Pl (l, control)", col="-Pl (l, control)"))+
  
  geom_point( size=3.5, data = Pot, shape=16)+labs(x="pH", y=expression(Cd~~~mg~(kg~soil)^{-1}))+
  geom_point(size=3.5, data=Pot1,  shape=17)+
  geom_point(size=3.5, data=Incub,  shape=2)+
  geom_point(size=3.5, data=Incub1,  shape=1)+
  geom_smooth(data = subset(data, Nu<53),formula= y ~ exp(1.5*-x), method = "lm", se=F, level=0.95, size=0.5,aes(col="+Pl ( Compost, FS, Fe)"))+
  geom_smooth(data = subset(data, Nu %in% c(53:64)),formula= y ~ exp(1.5*-x), method = "lm", se=F, level=0.95,size=0.5,linetype="dashed", col="black")+
  geom_smooth(data = subset(data, Nu %in% c(65:76)),formula= y ~ exp(1.5*-x), method = "lm", se=F, level=0.95,size=0.5,linetype="dashed", col="black")+
  geom_smooth(data = subset(data, Nu>76),formula= y ~ exp(1.5*-x), method = "lm", se=F, level=0.95, size=0.5,aes(col="-Pl ( Compost, FS, Fe)"))+
  stat_poly_eq(data = subset(data, Nu<53),formula= y ~ exp(1.5*-x),aes(label=paste(..rr.label..)),  
               label.x.npc = "left", label.y.npc = 0.03,  parse=T, size=6, col="black")+
  stat_poly_eq(data = subset(data, Nu=53:64),formula= y ~ exp(1.5*-x),aes(label=paste(..rr.label..)),  
               label.x.npc = "left", label.y.npc = 0.1,  parse=T, size=6, col="black")+
  
  stat_poly_eq(data = subset(data, Nu>76),formula= y ~ exp(1.5*-x),aes(label=paste( ..rr.label..)), 
               label.x.npc = "right", label.y.npc = 0.8, parse=T, size=6, col="black", vjust=2, show.legend=F)+
  stat_poly_eq(data = subset(data, Nu=65:76),formula= y ~ exp(1.5*-x),aes(label=paste(..rr.label..)), 
               label.x.npc = "right", label.y.npc = 0.9, parse=T, size=6, col="black", vjust=2, show.legend=F)+
   theme(legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size=17,face=1))+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(nrow = 2, byrow = T))+
  scale_colour_manual(labels=c(col="Pot liming", col="Incubation liming", col="Incubation", col="Pot"),values = c("black", "black", "black", "black"))+
  guides(col = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype=c(0,0), shape = c(1, 2, 16, 17), color="black")))

png(file="grafic1.png",height = 125, width = 150, unit ="mm", res = 300)
(mfrow=c(2,2))
ggarrange(p1,  ncol=1, nrow=1, common.legend = T, legend="bottom")
dev.off()
```

Hello, I am trying to split the legend in the plot into two rows. But it couldn't work. I would be grateful for any suggestion if somebody writes me a solution.The legend on the plot consists of one row I wanted to make it into two rows.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `nrow` in your `guides` function like this:

```r
library(gridExtra)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(tidyr)
library(ggpmisc)
library(ggpubr)
library(patchwork) # combine plots
library(gapminder)

p1=ggplot(data=data, aes(x=pH,y=Cd_ppm,col="+Pl (l, control)", col="-Pl (l, control)"))+
  
  geom_point( size=3.5, data = Pot, shape=16)+labs(x="pH", y=expression(Cd~~~mg~(kg~soil)^{-1}))+
  geom_point(size=3.5, data=Pot1,  shape=17)+
  geom_point(size=3.5, data=Incub,  shape=2)+
  geom_point(size=3.5, data=Incub1,  shape=1)+
  geom_smooth(data = subset(data, Nu<53),formula= y ~ exp(1.5*-x), method = "lm", se=F, level=0.95, size=0.5,aes(col="+Pl ( Compost, FS, Fe)"))+
  geom_smooth(data = subset(data, Nu %in% c(53:64)),formula= y ~ exp(1.5*-x), method = "lm", se=F, level=0.95,size=0.5,linetype="dashed", col="black")+
  geom_smooth(data = subset(data, Nu %in% c(65:76)),formula= y ~ exp(1.5*-x), method = "lm", se=F, level=0.95,size=0.5,linetype="dashed", col="black")+
  geom_smooth(data = subset(data, Nu>76),formula= y ~ exp(1.5*-x), method = "lm", se=F, level=0.95, size=0.5,aes(col="-Pl ( Compost, FS, Fe)"))+
  stat_poly_eq(data = subset(data, Nu<53),formula= y ~ exp(1.5*-x),aes(label=paste(..rr.label..)),  
               label.x.npc = "left", label.y.npc = 0.03,  parse=T, size=6, col="black")+
  stat_poly_eq(data = subset(data, Nu=53:64),formula= y ~ exp(1.5*-x),aes(label=paste(..rr.label..)),  
               label.x.npc = "left", label.y.npc = 0.1,  parse=T, size=6, col="black")+
  
  stat_poly_eq(data = subset(data, Nu>76),formula= y ~ exp(1.5*-x),aes(label=paste( ..rr.label..)), 
               label.x.npc = "right", label.y.npc = 0.8, parse=T, size=6, col="black", vjust=2, show.legend=F)+
  stat_poly_eq(data = subset(data, Nu=65:76),formula= y ~ exp(1.5*-x),aes(label=paste(..rr.label..)), 
               label.x.npc = "right", label.y.npc = 0.9, parse=T, size=6, col="black", vjust=2, show.legend=F)+
  theme(legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size=17,face=1))+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(nrow = 2, byrow = T))+
  scale_colour_manual(labels=c(col="Pot liming", col="Incubation liming", col="Incubation", col="Pot"),values = c("black", "black", "black", "black"))+
  guides(col = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype=c(0,0), shape = c(1, 2, 16, 17), color="black"),
                            nrow = 2))
#> Warning: Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` instead.
p1
#> Warning: The dot-dot notation (`..rr.label..`) was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `after_stat(rr.label)` instead.
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_smooth()`).
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_poly_eq()`).
#> Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_poly_eq()`).
#> Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_poly_eq()`).
#> Warning: Duplicated aesthetics after name standardisation: colour
#> Duplicated aesthetics after name standardisation: colour
#> Duplicated aesthetics after name standardisation: colour
#> Duplicated aesthetics after name standardisation: colour
#> Duplicated aesthetics after name standardisation: colour
#> Duplicated aesthetics after name standardisation: colour
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (`geom_point()`).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>